# Android: http login not having desired effect

Tags: android

I couldn't seem to get my log in page to work, it kept telling me my username/password were incorrect when I obviously know they are not. So I started debugging and popping in log.v's and I found something interesting. Look for the line that says "//<--- THIS LINE!"

```
class LogMeIn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.fakesite.com/login.php");

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            username = un.getText().toString();
            password = pw.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            String res = inputStream(response.getEntity().getContent())
                    .toString();
            Log.v("RESPONSE", res); // <--- THIS LINE!

            // if username and password are valid, launch main activity
            if (res.toString() == "1") {
                Intent logIn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                startActivity(logIn);                   
            } 
            // send the user a message saying the login failed
            else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {                         
                        pw.setText("");
                        fail.setText(R.string.fail);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    }
}

private StringBuilder inputStream(InputStream input) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

    try {
        while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Now I was expecting a response like "true" or "1". Based on that I would know the username/password was correct and I launch my main activity and life goes on. However what I got back was this

```
05-18 15:41:27.620: V/RESPONSE(27641):  <!--<script>window.location.href="";</script>-->       <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=">                -->
```

furthermore if I trim off the /login.php at the end of the URL to say "http://www.whatever.com" I get a wall of similar html just much longer.

Needless to say I'm doing this wrong, and my login fails regardless of whether the username/password is correct. Where did I go wrong? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I am also doing this and your code seems to be correct. The problem could lie on your server. The response you get looks like a redirection. (Maybe your server expects some headers in the request or something similar?)

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay That could very well be, I did not design the website, server or php file I'm trying to access. However I do have full access to the files. Where would I find this information? In the login.php?

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay upon looking into the login.php file, the function.php, and the server.php I found nothing that requests anything other than the username/password. *sigh* this is the life i chose. lol.

Comment: Try to make a request to my server: http://readmic.com/login posting "email" and "password" (don't send real data) and see it the answer is different.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay I just did what you said. It returns a wall of html tags starting with `05-18 16:47:35.900: V/RESPONSE(29778): <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>readmic.com | public/login</title>` and just goes from there listing all the content of your site as if I were to choose "view source" from my browser

Comment: sorry: try `/m/login` to get a mobile, JSON version. In any case, also the previous example demonstrates that your server is the issue here not the java code in your Android app.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay Ah! I see now, it actually gives me responses. Well that proves it, my code is right... darn. Hey I think I just figured something out. If your site has a /m/ for mobile mine may as well. Like I said I didn't design it, I will search