# Android: odd response, possible redirect from PHP login

Tags: php, android

So this is a follow up to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628452/android-http-login-not-having-desired-effect#comment23911537_16628452). I've tested the code in that post on other websites and I get valid responses and successful log ins. However on this site I get back what looks like a redirect. Here is the php file I'm trying to access.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL^ E_NOTICE);
//include the connection and variable defination page
include("include/server.php");
include("include/function.php");
//checking the form has been submit by user or not
if(isset($_POST['cmdSubmit']) and $_POST['cmdSubmit']="Login")
{   
//$refLink  = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$refLink    = "index.php?err_msg=1";
$user = addslashes($_POST['username']);
$pass = addslashes($_POST['password']);
$remember = $_POST['remember'];

$strErrorMessage = "";
if($user==""){
    $strErrorMessage = "User Name can not be blank";
}
if($pass==""){
    $strErrorMessage = "Password can not be blank";
}
if($user=="" and $pass==""){
    $strErrorMessage = "User Name and Password can not be blank";
}

if($strErrorMessage=="")
{

    if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
        //removing all the cookie at set the user name password in cookies
        unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);        
        setcookie("usernamex", $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24*100);
        setcookie("userpassx", $_POST['password'], time()+60*60*24*100);
        setcookie("rememberx", $_POST['remember'], time()+60*60*24*100);
    }else{
        if(isset($_COOKIE['rememberx']) && isset($_COOKIE['usernamex']) && isset($_COOKIE['userpassx']))
        {
            unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);        
            setcookie("usernamex", $_POST['username'], time());
            setcookie("userpassx", $_POST['password'], time());
            setcookie("rememberx", $_POST['remember'], time());
        }
    }

    $sqlLogin   = "select * from member_mast where username = '".$user."' and password = '".$pass."' and is_deleted_flg=0 and is_profile=0";        
    $queryLogin = mysql_query($sqlLogin) or die(mysql_error()." Please check the Query");
    $totLogin   = mysql_num_rows($queryLogin);      

    //here checking the user is authorized or not 
    if($totLogin>0)
    {
        $rsLogin                = mysql_fetch_array($queryLogin);   
        $_SESSION['uid']        = trim($rsLogin['username']);
        $_SESSION['memberid']       = trim($rsLogin['user_id']);
        $_SESSION['userType'] = trim($rsLogin['member_role']);

        if(isset($_POST["page"]) and trim($_POST["page"])!="")
        {
            $pageName       = trim($_POST["page"]);
            $pagepassId     = trim($_POST["pageid"]);
            $redirect_url   = "http://www.fakesite.com/fspv2/welcome.php?page=".$pageName."&pageid=".$pagepassId;
        }
        else
        {
            //$redirect_url = "http://www.fakesite.com/fspv2/welcome.php";
            //$redirect_url = "welcome.php";
            $redirect_url   = "welcome.php";
        }
//header("Location: ".$redirect_url);
?>
        <script>window.location.href="<?php echo $redirect_url; ?>";</script>
      <!--  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $redirect_url; ?>">    -->
<?php
}
else
{       
        $displayMessage = "Login failed. If you are authorized, try again";
        session_destroy();
        $state = "inv";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pass'];         
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $password = $_SESSION['password'];  
    ?>
        <script>window.location.href="<?php echo $refLink; ?>";</script>
    <?php       
    }
}
else
{   
    $state = "inv";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['userid'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pass'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $displayMessage = $strErrorMessage;
?>
    <script>window.location.href="<?php echo $refLink; ?>";</script>
<?php       
}  
}
 //header("Location: ".$refLink);
?>
<!--<script>window.location.href="<?php echo $refLink; ?>";</script>--> <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $refLink; ?>">  -->
```

Now when I connect to this login.php it doesnt matter if the username/pw is valid or not. The only response I get is this

```
05-18 17:08:50.160: V/RESPONSE(30797):  <!--<script>window.location.href="";</script>-->       <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=">                -->
```

Which looks as though it's `javascript` attempting to redirect me because it's a mobile device. The only redirect I can find in there is to redirect the client to the "welcome.php" which would be if they successfully logged in. I've gone through the files on the site and there does not appear to be a mobile login.php (i may be wrong). It should be noted I did not design the site I'm trying to log into and the site is operational and users can log in from this `php` file from their browser. I also have access to all the files. ***My question is why isn't this `php` file allowing me to login via my android app and instead giving me this odd response? *** If you need to see any other code please just ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the javascript is coming from is easy to answer:

```
?>
<!--<script>window.location.href="<?php echo $refLink; ?>";</script>--> <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $refLink; ?>">  -->
```

After your PHP tag ends, there is additional text. Namely the javascript. If you don't want that in the response, you'll need to remove it from the PHP file or put in a PHP if condition to make it only displayed in some contexts.

As far as you Android code goes, you need to add

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmdSubmit", "Login"));
```

Otherwise your first if (PHP) clause is false.

Comment: Sorry about that I got called away and wasn't able to add a comment above asking for your Android code that does the HTTP post.

Comment: it's listed in the link at the top of the question. Here it is again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628452/android-http-login-not-having-desired-effect#comment23911537_16628452

Comment: I just copied your code out into my editor because the braces were a little hard to follow. Everything in the PHP is wrapped in one big if statement that is testing to see if the HTTP POST coming from Android contains the cmdSubmit parameter and that it is set to "Login". Without that parameter, the output is only that last line containing the HTML comment wrapping that script tag. When you add that parameter, you will get back just a plain script tag (no HTML comment)

Comment: That makes sense, I just assumed that was only a local variable. As in that was a reference to the login button on the actual site. I will attempt this solution in a couple hours when i get home. Thanks for your help! I'll accept the answer if it works

Comment: So you were correct, it did need the reference to a submit button named login, it now gives me different responses based on correct/incorrect logins but I'm not sure what to do with them. Time for a new question I suppose. Thank you very much for your help!